# Promote Execution Context from JobStep to calling step

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm developing a small report-running framework to add to an application that uses Spring Batch for a number of integration tasks. The design consists of three steps:

1. Retrieve a Report Definition from a database table (contains a Job Name, static parameters to pass to job, list of users who receive the report) and put that into the Step/Job Execution Context. This step is accomplished via a tasklet.
2. Use the Report Definition in the Execution context to create a JobStep. The job would perform whatever logic that needs to be done and creates a file.
3. Distribute that file out to the users (probably another tasklet).

I would like it if the report generation job (the one run in Step 2), could put the file name created into it's execution context, where it could then be promoted into the parent job's execution context, so the last step can use that information, but I am not seeing any way to accomplish this as the JobExecution (from the generation job) seems to be scoped to the doExecute method and only used in setting the exit status of the Step.

Is there a means to pass this information along in the execution context? If not, I'm thinking I might need to subclass the JobStep class so that something equivalent to a ExecutionContextPromotionListener could be specified to promote those values from the child job to parent step.

Step Definition that uses the JobStep:

```
    @JobScope
    @Bean(name="runReportStep")
    Step buildRunReportStep(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['reportDefn']}") ReportDefinition rptDfn) {
        try {
            Job job = jobRegistry.getJob(rptDfn.getJobName());
            return new StepBuilder("runReportStep", jobRepository)
                    .job(job)
                    .launcher(jobLauncher)
                    .build();
        } catch (NoSuchJobException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

JobStep.doExecute (Spring Batch 5.1.0)

```
        /**
     * Execute the job provided by delegating to the {@link JobLauncher} to prevent
     * duplicate executions. The job parameters will be generated by the
     * {@link JobParametersExtractor} provided (if any), otherwise empty. On a restart,
     * the job parameters will be the same as the last (failed) execution.
     *
     * @see AbstractStep#doExecute(StepExecution)
     */
    @Override
    protected void doExecute(StepExecution stepExecution) throws Exception {

        ExecutionContext executionContext = stepExecution.getExecutionContext();

        executionContext.put(STEP_TYPE_KEY, this.getClass().getName());

        JobParameters jobParameters;
        if (executionContext.containsKey(JOB_PARAMETERS_KEY)) {
            jobParameters = (JobParameters) executionContext.get(JOB_PARAMETERS_KEY);
        }
        else {
            jobParameters = jobParametersExtractor.getJobParameters(job, stepExecution);
            executionContext.put(JOB_PARAMETERS_KEY, jobParameters);
        }

        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);

        stepExecution.setExitStatus(determineStepExitStatus(stepExecution, jobExecution));

        if (jobExecution.getStatus().isUnsuccessful()) {
            // AbstractStep will take care of the step execution status
            throw new UnexpectedJobExecutionException("Step failure: the delegate Job failed in JobStep.");
        }
        else if (jobExecution.getStatus().equals(BatchStatus.STOPPED)) {
            stepExecution.setStatus(BatchStatus.STOPPED);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no way to do that. Please open an issue on Github with a reference to this SO question and we will try to find the best way to make this possible.

Subclassing `JobStep` won't help as the job execution of the subjob is scoped to `doExecute`. Therefore, there is no way to get its execution context and promote keys to the parent step execution. This seems like a missing feature in Spring Batch to me.